# Prepend next element to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I´m trying to prepend a div (`.portrait_text`) to a container (`.gallery_container`):

Every image gets prepended to its corresponding `.gallery_container`. but I want to aslo prepend **every next** `.portrait_text` div to it´s `.gallery_container`. Any ideas?

```
<div id="gallery_images_inner" class="clearfix">
    <img src="img/portrait.jpg" alt="portrait" width="850" height="557">
    <div class="portrait_text">Girls After Swim</div>
    <img src="img/gallery5.jpg" alt="gallery5" width="850" height="566">
    <div class="portrait_text">Girls After Swim</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function Gallery(selector) {
    this.add_module = function (type, image) {
        var container = $('<div />', {
            'class': 'gallery_container'
        }).append(image);

        if (type == 'horizontal') {
            var h_ar = image.attr('height') / image.attr('width');
            var c_width = selector.width();
            var c_height = selector.width() * h_ar
            container.css({
                'width': c_width - 60,
                'height': c_height
            })
        }
        if (type == 'vertical') {
            var c_width = v_width;
            var c_height = v_height
            container.css({
                'width': Math.floor(v_width) - 30,
                'height': v_height
            })
        }
        container.css({
            'float': 'left',
            'overflow': 'hidden'
        })
        container.find('img').attr({
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '100%'
        })
        container.attr('ar', c_height / c_width)
        container.appendTo(selector);

        //container.children('img').fitToBox();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is appending, not prepending...do you actually mean prepend or not?

Comment: your title is says "prepend"

Comment: And the question description...please update it as this affects what the answer would be.

Comment: You might be looking for `.before()`, not `.prepend()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `image` is being passed as a jQuery object, as your code seems to suggest, you can use `.next()` to select the text as well:

```
function Gallery(selector) {
    this.add_module = function (type, image) {
        var portrait_text = image.next('.portrait_text');
        var container = $('<div />', {
            'class': 'gallery_container'
        }).append(image).append(portrait_text);
        ...
    }
}
```

Of course, this is **appending** and you asked for **prepending**, but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a [next selector](http://api.jquery.com/next/), so you can do

`$(selector).next(".portrait_text").appendTo(container);`